# Jahia : Add 2 mixins in a choicelist initializer?

Tags: java, mixins, jcr, jahia

I have a [choicelist initializer](https://academy.jahia.com/documentation/techwiki/content/content-editing-uis#ChoiceList_initializers) that allows a user to choose 'image' or 'video'. I need that :

- if the 'video' type is selected, apply mixin `umix:video`
- if the 'image' type is selected, apply mixins `umix:image` **and** `umix:link`

Is it possible ?

Here is a minimal example of what I have (question is in the code as a comment) :

**definitions.cnd** :

```
[unt:homeHeader] > jnt:content
 - type (string, choicelist[homeHeaderTypeListInitializer,resourceBundle]) = 'image' mandatory autocreated nofulltext

[umix:video] > jmix:templateMixin mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader
 - video (weakreference, picker[type='video'])  i18n mandatory < jnt:file

[umix:image] > jmix:templateMixin mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader
 - image (weakreference, picker[type='image'])  i18n mandatory < jnt:file

[umix:link] > jmix:templateMixin mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader
 - title (string) i18n < '^.{1,255}$'
 - url (string) = 'https://' i18n mandatory indexed=no
```

**homeHeaderTypeListInitializer.java** :

```
public List<ChoiceListValue> getChoiceListValues(ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd, String param, List<ChoiceListValue> values, Locale locale, Map<String, Object> context) {
        List<ChoiceListValue> myChoiceList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (context == null) {
            return myChoiceList;
        }
        HashMap<String, Object> myPropertiesMap;

        myPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        myPropertiesMap.put("addMixin", "umix:image");
        // HOW CAN I ADD THE SECOND MIXIN umix:link HERE ?
        myChoiceList.add(new ChoiceListValue("image", myPropertiesMap, new ValueImpl("image", PropertyType.STRING, false)));

        myPropertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        myPropertiesMap.put("addMixin", "umix:video");
        myChoiceList.add(new ChoiceListValue("video", myPropertiesMap, new ValueImpl("video", PropertyType.STRING, false)));

        return myChoiceList;
    }
```

I know that I can make a single mixin with all the properties from `umix:image` and `umix:link`, etc. but I want to know if there is any option to avoid that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, did you try something like this in the cnd file? The idea would be to add a new umix:videoimage that embed many mixins. Maybe it would solve your issue...

```
[umix:videoMix] mixin
 - video (weakreference, picker[type='video'])  i18n mandatory < jnt:file

[umix:imageMix] mixin
 - image (weakreference, picker[type='image'])  i18n mandatory < jnt:file


[umix:video] > umix:templateMixin,umix:videoMix mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader

[umix:image] > umix:templateMixin,umix:imageMix mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader

[umix:videoimage] > umix:templateMixin,umix:videoMix,umix:imageMix mixin
 extends = unt:homeHeader
```